# Find/replace in Microsoft Word to format only a portion of a word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word file that contains a product name that is partially italicized, like this: *e*Product

It seems that using find/replace, you can only apply formatting to the entire result.

I don't want to manually apply formatting in each case. Is there a way to find/replace to accomplish this? I'd also be open to using a variable or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

- Search for "eProduct" and replace it with a wholly italicized "*eUniqueWord*".
- Then search for the italicized "*UniqueWord*" and replace it with an upright "Product".

Comment: This works in a pinch. Working with Word always makes me appreciate (and miss) InDesign's style grep feature.